# Need assistance with jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Heys guys, I am currently using jquery and ajax to create a webpage. I am using ajax to load a web page that is using a jquery plugin(light-box plugin). The jquery plugin does not seem to work on this ajax loaded page but works properly when the page when it is loaded individually. So is this some problem with the plugin because of which the page is not loading and is there any solution to it.

Comment: is the plugin located in the by ajax loaded part or not?

Comment: How about showing some code? Maybe set up a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page is loaded on its own the page load event will be fired bu this won't happen if loaded through AJAX. You need to call the same javascript after the ajax call has completed

So whatever is in

```
 $(document).ready(function () ..
```

or

```
 $(function ()
```

you need to also call after the ajax has completed

Answer (score 1):

Without some code/markup it's hard to guess what is wrong but this is a possible solution:

You probably use document.ready to set up the script. because the elements that are loaded through ajax aren't in the dom yet the binding isn't going to work.

try the .live() http://api.jquery.com/live/