# Create Navigation with jQuery and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, getjson

The navigation (styled with Bootstrap 4) is simply **li elements**  and the **ul container** waiting for AJAX is

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills lead" id="navitems"></ul>
```

Creating an initial nav list with two static (non JSON) items with **jQuery .html**:

```
$("#navitems").html('
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link pcl" href="#" id="load_page1">Nav Link 1</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link pcl" href="#" id="load_page2">Nav Link 2</a></li>
');
```

Adding further items with **JSON / AJAX**

```
$.getJSON(cfcJSON+'&asite='+asite+'&apost='+apost+'&asort='+asort,      
  function(data) {
    $.each(data.DATA.NAVITEMS, function(i,navitems){
      $('#navitems').append(navitems);  
        return false;   // all li items in one string   
    });
 });
```

**Codepen** http://codepen.io/xsmobi/pen/MbpxbE (important: not using https)

To be sure that is has not to do with Codepen, I hosted the page here, too
    https://www.bitballoon.com/sites/testing-ajax-navigation

**In both cases**

- Building the navigation with jQuery works
- Only those two test links created with ().html() are able to fire
- Those created with AJAX aren't
- Checking elements in developer tools: links look the same (see screenshot in the code)

This is the on.click function, it works for the non-getJSON links

```
pdx = 0;
$('.pcl').click(function() {
console.log("clicked in doc ready slogan");
pdxx = pdx;
pdx = this.id;
$(".pcl").removeClass('active');
$("#"+pdx).addClass('active');
pdx = pdx.replace("load_", "");
console.log("Nav li clicked with anchor text ...: " + pdx + "!")
});
```

Tried
[Need assistance with jquery and ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402053/need-assistance-with-jquery-and-ajax)
and wrapped the on.click in a doc ready (nested in the main document ready) but that does not help

Answer (score 1):

The click event you have written for `.pcl` element was not attaching with dynamic elements i.e. elements through `ajax` or after `DOM load`, since the `click event` would be done with attaching events before your elements get appended in `DOM`. So what you need here **[`event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**. You can try attaching the event with `document`, targeting specific class `$(document).on('click','.pcl',function() {` instead of `$('.pcl').click(function(){`

So your updated code would be as:

```
$(document).on('click','.pcl',function() {
    console.log("clicked in doc ready slogan");
    pdxx = pdx;
    pdx = this.id;
    $('.pcl').removeClass('active');
    $("#"+pdx).addClass('active');
    pdx = pdx.replace("load_", "");
    console.log("Nav li clicked with anchor text ...: " + pdx + "!")
});
```

and here is the **[Updated pen](http://codepen.io/kshkrao3/pen/vyxqxq?editors=1111)**

Comment: Thanks a lot, Guruprasad, for your quick and complete help, all the more without blaming me for my lack of unterstanding. Once the project is running, I am going to add you to the list of coding angels.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :) In the mean time you can **tick the right mark** to the left of the answer, which means you accept the answer.. :)

Comment: Of course, id _did_ tick it, but SO responded that my ticks are not published as yet due to my low level so far. Howerer it's being counted, so you have the score.
Added a link to your SO profile, it's in the comment to the respective [Codepen](http://codepen.io/xsmobi/pen/MbpxbE)